# How to manage to different button to open Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three button : button 1 , button 2 and button submit.All these buttons are in same activity. The concept is,
When I click on the button 1 and then press button submit, then fragment 1 open. The same way when I click on button 2 and press button submit then fragment 2 open. Please help me to solve this concept.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think button1 and button2 should be radio buttons. So when you press submit button, based on the radio selection it will open fragment1 or fragment2.

Comment: Here all three are buttons, I don't have to use radio buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is simple.

**Global Scope variable** `int flag;`

While you are click button1 make flag=1.

if you are clicked botton2 make flag=2.

Then in onclick of submit,check the value of flag.

If flag=1 then go to fragment1,else flagment2.

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           flag=1;
           }
        });
button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           flag=2;
           }
        });

submitbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
           if(flag==1){
              //go to fragment1
           } else{
              //go to fragment2}
           }
        });
```

Comment: if(flag==1) sorry for the mistyping :)

Comment: Thank you very much @user9733846

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will work for you.

```
int flag; 
//define it globally.

//on first button click set flag to 1.

 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                flag = 1;
            }
        });

     //on second button click set flag to 2.

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                flag = 2;
            }
        });

 btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (flag == 1) {
                    //open here fragment 1
                } else if (flag == 2) {
                    //open here fragment 2
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: What's diff between your ans and other answer given above?

Answer (score 0):

```
    int flag=0;


    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            flag = 1;
        }
    });

    for button2 set flag=2 and so on...

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (flag == 1) {

                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,FragmentsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("fragment_id","1");
                startActivity(intent);

            } else if (flag == 2) {

                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,FragmentsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("fragment_id","2");
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            //so on....
        }
    });


    // On your FragmentActivity 

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    String fragment_id=intent.getStringExtra("fragment_id");

    //set this fragment_id to the viewpager of your fragments..

 viewPager.setCurrentItem(Integer.parseInt(string));
```